# Windows 7 low and critical battery levels cannot be set lower than 10%

Tags: windows-7, sleep, battery, shutdown, hibernate

How do I change the low and critical battery levels to below 10%? I understand that this is a reasonable limit for most portable computers, but what about those with large batteries? On my computer (which has two batteries) 10% is an hour of runtime and is therefore way too high.

Answer (score 4):

Search Power Options in your Start Menu and choose the first Control Panel option.

Choose `Change Plan Settings` on the power scheme of your choice.

Choose `Change Advanced Power Settings`.

Scroll to the bottom of the config box that pops up. Open up the battery section. Your options are there.

Keep in mind that some batteries have firmware that kills the battery below 5% to keep the battery from being forever destroyed or destroying the system it's being used in.

Comment: +1 for the warnings. Running them that low kills their charge cycles.